# Проблемы при считывании строки с помощью getchar() в C

Tags: c

Всем привет! Пытаюсь реализовать программу, которая заполняет массив структур Студентов на Си (на самом деле, просто близком к нему C++):

```
    char *readLine() {
        char *str = new char[1];

        char ch = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && (ch != '\0')) {
            str[i++] = ch;

            char *copyStr = new char[i + 1];
            strncpy(copyStr, str, i);

            delete[] str;
            str = copyStr;
        }
        str[i] = '\0';

        return str;
    }

    int maint() {
        struct AAA {
            char* surname;
            char* name;
            char* sss;
            double score;
        };

        AAA* aaa = new AAA[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("Данные о %d студенте \n", i + 1);
            printf("Фамилия: ");
            aaa[i].surname = readLine();
            printf("Имя: ");
            aaa[i].name = readLine();
            printf("Отчество: ");
            aaa[i].sss = readLine();
            printf("Средний балл: ");
            scanf("%lf", &aaa[i].score);

            printf(aaa[i].surname);
            printf("\n");
            printf(aaa[i].name);
            printf("\n");
            printf(aaa[i].sss);
            printf("\n");
            printf("%f\n", aaa[i].score);
        }
    }
```

Но на выходе получаю это:

```
Введите номер задания: 19
Данные о 1 студенте 
Фамилия: Имя: asd
Отчество: dsa
Средний балл: 100

asd
dsa
100.000000
```

Программа игнорирует строку `aaa[i].surname = readLine();`. Почему?

Comment: Что значит "игнорирует"? Какой текст подается на вход? Чтение строки, кстати, довольно неоптимальное, хотя, может бытб, с IO короткими строками это не столь заметно.

Comment: @bipll дополнил ответ

Comment: @bipll чтение, к слову, оптимально, просто не по времени, а по памяти

Comment: Разумно уйти от этого кода или в чистый `С`, или в чистый `С++` А это помесь козла с молотком :) и если это будет С, то `strndup()` вам в помощь вместо нев всяких..

Comment: И поменяйте устаревший морально `getchar` на что либо более производительное, например: `char *ptr = fgets(buffer, MAXLINESIZE, stdin)) {..}` или [`readline`](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)   который более подходит для этих целей.